# htaccess redirection is not working as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't know much more about how to write htaccess code for redirection.

Now currently my url is: http://example.com/beta/?selector=login.
above link will open a login page.

Login page available here: page/login.php

And I have write following code in index.php:

```
<?php
include ("page/header.php");
if(isset($_GET['selector'])){
      if($_GET['selector']=="feed") { include ("feeds/index.php"); }
      else { include ("page/".$_GET['selector'].".php"); }
}
else{
    include ("page/home.php");
}
include ("page/header.php");
?>
```

Now I want instead of above link is http://example.com/beta/login

I have written the following code in htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: did you enable the module in apache?

Comment: yes i have enable module :)

Comment: In what directory your htaccess file is placed?

Comment: beta/.htaccess
beta/index.php
beta/page/login.php
if selector=feed then it will open file feed/index.php
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^feed/?$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?selector=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: yes it is working but there is only one issue.
issue is that : 
http://mydomain.com/beta/?selector=feed

the feed file appear inside 
feed directory means
feed/index.php

this is only one issue.

Comment: i did not quite get the issue. sorry. can you clarify it further? thanks!

Comment: w8, isnt this the default behavior of web servers? if you put /beta/feed it will open /beta/feed/index.php by default?

Comment: use the previous code, then be sure to trim the selector from slashes.. what does the value of `var_dump($_GET['selector']);` output?

Comment: echo var_dump($_GET['selector']); = "feed"

Comment: then what is the issue again?

Comment: all other will go to page/$_GET['selector'].php

Comment: ahh, its because of the line.. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` since you have a feed directory a.k.a `/feed/` try to remove that line. then trim your selector feed like this `trim($_GET['selector'],'/');`

Comment: is `/feed/` a special case? because i would need to modify the code for that so it would be cleaner..

Comment: your code is already working its my mistake :)
that i have use same request and directory